# Show difference in records - MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, expression, vba

I have a subform with the following layout:

```
ID---Count---Difference---Weight---Difference
```

Populated with data looks like this:

```
ID---Count---Difference---Weight---Difference
1----5--------------------8.3----------------
2----9--------------------12.3---------------
3----16-------------------17.8---------------
```

How can I tell the difference between a record value and the one before it?  Using the previous example, I'd like the Difference controls to look like so:

```
ID---Count---Difference---Weight---Difference
1----5-------0------------8.3------0---------
2----9-------4------------12.4-----4.1-------
7----16------7------------17.8-----5.4-------
```

As you can see, since record ID 1 is the first record, the difference is 0; however, ID 2 shows a Count Difference of 4 (9-5) and a Weight Difference of 4.1 (12.4 - 8.3); and ID 7 
shows a Count Difference of 7 (16-9) and a Weight Difference of 5.4 (17.8 - 12.4).

Also note that the ID #'s do not necessarily increment one-by-one (there can be gaps).

How can I achieve the desired results?  Expressions?  VBA?

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!